# Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG returning null

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {         
  try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    String nm = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String st1 = intent.getStringExtra("state");
    Log.v("nikhil","i="+intent+" name="+nm+" 2="+st1);

    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);

  } catch(Exception e) {            

    Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
  }
  return null; 
}
```

nm and st1 gets null all the time.
Even when headset is plugged in!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Intent Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG is fired by the Android system when a headset is plugged in or pulled out of the hand set.

You need to implement a BroadcastReceiver to catch this event as it happens. 
This is a sticky event, so you can use the following shortcut:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
Intent headsetState= this.registerReceiver(null, filter);
int state = headsetState.getIntExtra("state", -1);
String name = headsetState.getStringExtra("name");
```